# JFrame drawing two to three items when only one is included in my Squares arraylist

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, rect

Title. I have created a Square class that defines what a square is, and lets me create a square with certain parameters. Whenever I add one square to the squares arraylist, it ends up drawing two to three. Why does it do this? I've even made it print the number of arraylist items (squares.size()) into the console, and it says only one. Also, the background turns grey whenever I draw a square. How can I fix that?

Edit: It also seems to randomly draw the squares again - or at least print the messages in the console whenever I move the window around, however it doesn't always happen.

My square class (getters + setters not included):

```
public class Square {
    public static ArrayList<Square> squares = new ArrayList<Square>();

    public int x, y, width, height;
    public Color color;

    public Square(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color color) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

My main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static String name = "Project";

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MessageUtils.sendConsole(name + " started.");

        Square.squares.add(new Square(50, 50, 150, 150, Color.black));

        Frame frame = new Frame();
    }
}
```

And my frame class:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {

    public Frame() {
        super(Main.name);

        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        setResizable(false);
        setSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        MessageUtils.sendConsole("Frame setup.");
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        int count = 1;
        for (Square s : Square.squares) {
            g.drawRect(s.getX(), s.getY(), s.getWidth(), s.getHeight());
            g.setColor(s.getColor());
            g.fillRect(s.getX(), s.getY(), s.getWidth(), s.getHeight());
            MessageUtils.sendConsole("Square #" + count + " drawn.");
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Don't override paint() of a JFrame. 2) Instead you override paintComponent()  of a JPanel  and the first statement should be super.paintComponent() to make sure the background is cleared. 3) the panel is then added to the frame. Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: @camickr okay, but why is it drawing multiple squares if I only put one in the arraylist? And as time moves on, why does it continue to draw even more squares?

Comment: The background isn't cleared and there is garbage being painted. You need to follow the proper painting guidelines or this is what can happen.